# While command keeps increasing x value by 2 instead of 1

Tags: php, mysql

So my aim here is to get the value of a checked radio button and compare it with the database answer I have. However, when I do the while loop $x goes from 0 to 2 when I do $x++;
Main page and result page posted below. Thanks in advance for your help.

**Main.php**

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_WARNING);
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","mcq");

//connection check
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  };
  //get questions
  $questions = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT `ID`, `Question`, `Answer` FROM `main`");
  $answers = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT `ans1`, `ans2`, `ans3`, `ans4` FROM `answerlist`");
  echo("<form action='result.php' method='post'>");
  if ($questions->num_rows > 0){
    // output data of each row
    while(($row = $questions->fetch_assoc()) && ($row1 = $answers->fetch_assoc())) {

        echo ($row[ID].". ".$row[Question]."<br/>"."<input type='radio' name='id".$row[ID]."' value='".$row1[ans1]."'/>".$row1[ans1]."<br/>"."<input type='radio' name='id".$row[ID]."' value='".$row1[ans2]."'/>".$row1[ans2]."<br/>"."<input type='radio' name='id".$row[ID]."' value='".$row1[ans3]."'/>".$row1[ans3]."<br/>"."<input type='radio' name='id".$row[ID]."' value='".$row1[ans4]."'/>".$row1[ans4]);

    }
};
echo("<br/><button type='submit'>SUBMIT</button>");
echo("</form>");



?>
```

**Result.php**

```
<?php
$count = 0;
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","mcq");

//connection check
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
};

$questions = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT `ID`,`Answer` FROM `main`");

$qcount = count(mysqli_fetch_assoc($questions));
$x = 1;
while($x < $qcount){

$id = "id".$x;
$answerval = $_POST["$id"];

while($row = $questions->fetch_assoc()){
    print_r($row);
    $ans = $row['Answer'];
if($answerval == $ans){
    $count= $count + 1;
    echo("TRUE");

};

 };
     };
    echo("<br/>".$count);


?>
```

Comment: There is no `$x++` in your code

Comment: you have two while loops and `$count` is getting incrementing in the inner nested while loop. This basically implies that you are getting two rows matching `$answerval` from the database

Comment: (Not the error but )You may be missing some warnings/notice messages as in `$row[ID]` and others like this, you should have quotes round the index `$row['ID']`

Comment: You are retrieving the questions and answers from 2 separate SQL statements and at no point do you sort them or check that the answer is for the question being displayed.

Comment: in the first page I am using two tables to keep Q and A's separate. I have the answer in the Q table and options in A table. My $count is to count right answers

Comment: i had removed the $x++ momentarily to try fix